# download all images from webpage using c#

Tags: c#, html

Im trying to save a webpage so i can view it offline. i menaged to get the html from an  webpage but i can't figure out how to get all the images.

here is the code i use to get the html:

```
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(txtUrl.Text);
            HttpWebResponse responce = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responce.GetResponseStream());
            string responsehtml = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();

            string path = @"C:\Users\Cargoguide\Pictures\test\test.htm";
            File.WriteAllText(path, responsehtml);
            Process.Start(path);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can let winform's WebBrowser control do the hard work. After it parses the webpage, you can navigate through Images elements to save each image.

```
private void GetWebpage(string url)
{
    WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
    browser.Navigate(url);
    browser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(browser_DocumentCompleted);

}

void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var browser = (WebBrowser)sender;
    var client = new WebClient();
    foreach (var img in browser.Document.Images)
    {
        var image = img as HtmlElement;
        var src = image.GetAttribute("src").TrimEnd('/');
        if (!Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(src, UriKind.Absolute))
        {
            src = string.Concat(browser.Document.Url.AbsoluteUri, "/", src);
        }

        //Append any path to filename as needed
        var filename = new string(src.Skip(src.LastIndexOf('/')+1).ToArray());
        File.WriteAllBytes(filename, client.DownloadData(src));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. this is excactly what i need.